# Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex

**Class**

```
private List<Contact> RepCombinedAttachment;
Public List<CombinedAttachment> RepComAttachment;

public List<CombinedAttachment> getRepComAttachment() {
    return RepComAttachment;
} 
public CombinedAttachmentcont(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

     ViewData();
 }
public void ViewData()
{
    RepCombinedAttachment = Database.query('Select (Select id, title, LastModifiedDate,
        createdby.name,RecordType From CombinedAttachments) from Contact where ID=:id');

    for (Contact c : RepCombinedAttachment)
    {
        for(CombinedAttachment temp : c.CombinedAttachments)
        {
            if(!temp.isEmpty())
            RepComAttachment.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [CombinedAttachment].isEmpty()

Could someone please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(CombinedAttachment temp : c.CombinedAttachments)
{
        //if(!temp.isEmpty())
        RepComAttachment.add(temp);
 }
```

`isEmpty()` is the **list class method** in order to check sobject. You may want to use any field is null or not

remove `if(!temp.isEmpty())`

---

Edit

in constructor

```
public CombinedAttachmentcont(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     RepCombinedAttachment = new List<Contact>();
     RepComAttachment = new  List<CombinedAttachment>();
     ViewData();
 }
```

Comment: I removed it, but getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object " error. while executing visualforce page.

Comment: hey @Dinesh can you just point me in which you are getting error?  It will be better if you add complete code

Comment: public List<CombinedAttachment> getRepComAttachment()
{return RepComAttachment;}

public CombinedAttachmentcont(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

 ViewData();

}      Below the viewdata(), I have just the above code.

Comment: VF Code: <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Notes & Attachments" id="CApageBlock">
       
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!RepComAttachment}" var="a">        
       
      <apex:column value="{!a.RecordType}"/>
           
        </apex:pageblocktable>        
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>

Comment: @Dinesh check my updated ans

Comment: Thanks Ratan. How this change fixed the issue. Could you give me an idea, please..

Comment: @Dinesh so what happend initially when we declare  a variable `List<Contact> RepCombinedAttachment`  it always contain null. untill unless we initialize the variable  `new List<Contact>();` now it contains empty list

Comment: There is lot to learn..Thank you so much for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code in following way

```
for ( Contact c : RepCombinedAttachment)
{
      //Check for isEmpty first and then do the loop.
      if(!c.CombinedAttachments.isEmpty())
      {
        for(CombinedAttachment temp : c.CombinedAttachments)
        {
            RepComAttachment.add(temp);
        }
     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ratan already explained, the following is the issue you are asking about:

```
for(CombinedAttachment temp : c.CombinedAttachments)
{
  //if(!temp.isEmpty())
  RepComAttachment.add(temp);
}
```

temp is an object variable, not a collection.  There is no isEmpty on it.

Your second issue is that you aren't bringing back any records from your query.  You have no variable called 'id', yet you are trying to query by it.  You need to fix the following query:

```
RepCombinedAttachment = Database.query('Select (Select id, title, LastModifiedDate,
        createdby.name,RecordType From CombinedAttachments) from Contact where ID=:id');
```

EDIT:

Just look at Ratan's edit to his answer.  It should now be correct.

Comment: I have declared, id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');. still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dinesh Where is your error?  Update your question please.

Comment: Just look at Ratan's edit to his answer.  It should now be correct.